# Unable to set root directory headers with htaccess, 1and1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My issue is that I cannot move my .htaccess file one directory back e.g. ../
due to hosting limitations...

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?gw2pvp\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/main/
RewriteRule (.*) /main/$1 [L]

Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' //ajax.googleapis.com"
```

What this is doing is setting /main as the root directory, so that when i goto the main website my files in /main are shown instead.

The issue here is that my headers won't set now. Is there anyway to trick it into setting headers here?

My website: http://gw2pvp.com
loading http://gw2pvp.com/sdgshsg will load correct headers.... (non existant directory)
going into http://gw2pvp.com/main/ doesn't work either.

i guess this rules out the possibility of cloudflare being the issue, and also that the directives work in htaccess.

one thing i noticed is that it works for everything but PHP files...

e.g. http://gw2pvp.com/main/test.html works.

this would indiciate that this is working fine and *something* else is not letting me set headers here..

Comment: "one thing i noticed is that it works for everything but PHP files..." That helped me out - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stackoverflow\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum/
RewriteRule (.*) /forum/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

`%{HTTP_HOST}` matches only hostname without protocol or scheme.

Comment: This helps greatly, however I'm still having issues setting headers. I was thinking maybe cloudflare is unsetting headers or soemthing?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about `cloudflare`. I can only assist for rewrite issues.